# Notation (Tf)(x) of linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, operator-theory

I am confused about the following notation of a linear operator:

*Define the linear operator $T: L^2(0,1)\rightarrow L^2(0,1)$ by $(Tf)(x)=\int^1_0 (x+t)f(t) dt$*

I am confused about the notation $(Tf)(x)$. I have only seen operators of the form $Tx$ or $Tf(x)$, so operators where $x$ and $f(x)$ are the variables. But in $(Tf)(x)$ is the variable $f(x)$ or $x$? And if the variable is $x$, what does the $f$ do then?

Comment: If it makes you feel better, write it as $(T(f))(x)$ rather than $(Tf)(x)$

Comment: Can I write it as Tf(x)? I still don't understand it

Comment: Another way to think about $T$ if you know convolutions: it takes a function $f$, flips it about the $y$-axis to obtain $\tilde{f}$ (i.e.  $\tilde{f}(t) = f(-t)$), and then convolves it with the function $g$ defined by $g(x) = x$ when $-1 \leq x \leq 0$ and $g(x) = 0$ otherwise. In brief, $T$ defines a slightly modified convolution with a sawtooth impulse.

Answer (score 2):

The argument to $T$ is $f$, that returns a function which is given an argument called $x$.

The specification of what $T$ does involves the argument ($x$) of it's argument $f$.

As it totally leaves out $f$, $Tx$ is not an appropriate notation here. $Tf(x)$ basically means the same as $(Tf)(x)$, i.e. "apply $T$ to $f$, and evaluate the resulting function at $x$".

The notation $T(f(x))$ that is suggested in a comment is not as good, as $f(x)$ is a value in $\operatorname{Im} f$. And it is (probably, we haven't been told anything about $f$) not in $L^2(0,1)$ where $T$ is defined. It's common (especially at lower levels) to use $f(x)$ as notation for the function $f$, and if viewed like that, it's technically not wrong, but I find it unfortunate when you then have to evaluate the result.